# Setting TextInput state in onEndEditing

Tags: react-native

In the examples I always see settings TextInput state in onChangeText event. Everytime this is done, render is triggered even if the user is not done filling in the field which wastes renders. Why not do it in onEndEditing which is only triggered once when the user is actually done? Is there some drawbacks or something I am not seeing? Exactly what advantage does onChangeText provide over this approach?

```
onEndEditing={(event) => this.setState{value: event.nativeEvent.text}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a syntax error in your code.

```
onEndEditing={(event) => this.setState({value: event.nativeEvent.text}) }
```

and `onChangeText`  is **Callback** that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed text is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler.

And '`onEndEditing`' occurs when there is **no focusing** in `TextInput`.